# How to implement state inheritance in C++ state machine framework

Tags: c++, finite-state-machine

My first introduction to object-oriented UML statecharts was the book "Practical Statecharts in C/C++" by Miro Samek.  He proposes a framework in which the state machine is a single class and each state is a method within the class.  Once you have developed a state machine, it is easy to inherit/extend its behavior simply by marking these state methods as virtual and overriding in a subclass.

However, this design has a few (in my opinion) major problems:

1. Event handlers are a large switch statement inside the state method (not easy to read, gets large, SonarQube complains, and not very OOPish)
2. All extended state variables must be members of the state machine class even if they are not used in 99% of the states (i.e., no state-local storage)

With these problems in mind, I found the Boost statecharts library which has a more elegant solution.  Each state is its own class and each event "handler" is a method in the class.  The "enter" and "exit" actions then become the constructors and destructors of these state classes.

Reading through the "rationale" and "performance" pages (https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/statechart/doc/rationale.html and https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/statechart/doc/performance.html) I noticed that they made a few decisions that I do not agree with in the context of embedded systems:

1. Allocation of states uses the heap (or a custom allocator)
2. They use a custom RTTI/dynamic_cast solution to dispatch to event handlers

I understand the reasoning behind (2), which is that using the "visitor" pattern tightly couples all states thus requiring recompilation of all in case of a change.  However, I believe that in most of my small embedded system applications, this is not really an issue.

So, I developed my own library which uses std::variant to store the child states directly within their parent.  In this way, a state machine's memory footprint may be statically defined.  I also use the GoF visitor pattern to dispatch events into the machine.  The implementation is not very complex and can be seen here: https://github.com/pwsoftwaredesigns/lib-pw-hsm/

However, I cannot think of a solution which allows me to inherit from an existing state hierarchy and extend it.  Because the state hierarchy is statically-defined (via the std::variants), I cannot think of a method to allow the user to inherit from a state (or states) and have those inserted into the existing hierarchy.

I would appreciate some guidance, advice, and direction on any possible solutions.

Comment: I don´t have time for a proper answer now, but your choices for GOF visitor, std::variant and having the states do the transitions with explicitly naming target types have painted you into a corner that doesn't have a path to inheritance.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau That was my fear/hunch, I just wanted to see if anyone had some creative solutions.